# How to make all images fit in same size div

Tags: javascript, html, css, styled-components

[image]

I want them to all fit inside the boxes with the border but I don't want them to appear stretched. how can I do this?

I have tried giving them a fixed height, width inside a div etc but they always appear to not look quite right

```
<CategoryContainer>
    <CategoryLink to={`${category.name.toLowerCase()}`}>
        <CategoryImage>
            <Image image={category.products[0].image} />
        </CategoryImage>
        <CategoryName>
            {`${category.name}`}
        </CategoryName>
    </CategoryLink>
</CategoryContainer>
```

and my styled components is:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
`;

export const CategoryContainer = styled.div`
  height: 300px;
  width: 33%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;

export const CategoryLink = styled(Link)`
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
`;

export const CategoryImage = styled.div`
`

export const CategoryName = styled.div`

`
```

Comment: Please include the rendered HTML & CSS ...

Comment: `max-height: 100%;  max-width: 100%;` should work in most browsers, I remember that potentially causing a compatibility issue somewhere (I think it was safari) but it was a few years ago and may be ironed out by now. You need to not set an explicit height or width though, because that will cause it to skew. Just the two `max` properties and nothing else.

Comment: @jmcgriz `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; width: auto;` will be sufficient I believe.

Comment: @DeepakKamat but which component above do I apply these to?

Comment: The image, the `img` tags inside of the whichever container you are putting them.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly simple idea is to keep the width relative to the height. Generally most responsive images' height is controlled by its width by setting  `height: auto` and `width: 100%`, we can just reverse this since in your case the height is variable.

```
.the-images {
  /* This is where magic happens */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;

  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or to maintain aspect ratio if the boxes are fluid in width, you can do this

```
.the-images {

  /* This is where magic happens */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;

  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

A live example:

http://jsbin.com/vuduvev/edit?css,output

Answer (score 0):

If setting the image as a background is an option:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

If not, use object-fit: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/